# Inserting image into canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to use the method `mCanvas.drawBitmap(iconBitmap,x-100,y-100, mBitmapPaint);` on my `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event in my custom view class. However, the image I want to show does not appear on the canvas at that point. I am trying to make a paint application where users can draw free hand and insert images at the same time to play with them.

This is my custom view class:

```
package com.example.shazs.autismate;
public class PaintView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 20;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.RED;
public static final int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private boolean emboss;
private boolean blur;
private MaskFilter mEmboss;
private MaskFilter mBlur;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Bitmap iconBitmap;
private static AtomicBoolean drawIcon = new AtomicBoolean();
public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void normal() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = false;
}

public void emboss() {
    emboss = true;
    blur = false;
}

public void blur() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = true;
}

public void setPaintColor(int color){
    if (currentColor!=color)
        Log.d("xyzn","current color changed");
    else
        Log.d("xyzn","current color not changed");
    currentColor=color;

}

public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bm){
    drawIcon.set(true);
    iconBitmap = bm;
}


public int getPaintColor(){
    return currentColor;
}
public void clear() {
    backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    paths.clear();
    normal();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    for (FingerPath fp : paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

        if (fp.emboss)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
        else if (fp.blur)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

        mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);

    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath);
    paths.add(fp);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            if (drawIcon.get()){
                mCanvas.drawBitmap(iconBitmap,x-100,y-100, mBitmapPaint);
                mCanvas.save();

                break;
            }
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            if (drawIcon.get())
                break;
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            if (drawIcon.get()){
                drawIcon.set(false);
                break;
            }
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Main Activity which uses this custom view class and passes the bitmap of object to draw:

```
public class drawActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

private PaintView paintView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.css_layout);
    paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.paintView);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.draw:
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple);
            paintView.drawBitmap(bm);
            break;
```

I use `drawIcon` to see if the user needs to insert icon or just draw freehand.

Interestingly, when I go into application view of my phone to view all currently running applications, the icon/image shows on the canvas. However when I return to the application, it dissappears. It only happens once after I insert the icon, not repeatedly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Please see edited post

Comment: Is `drawBitmap(Bitmap bm)` being called before touching? I don't see it initialized at the point of touching. So it might be null?

Comment: I am using a main activity that calls this drawBitmap(Bitmap bm) to pass the bitmap of the object I want to draw. This method sets the bitmap and the atomic boolean `drawIcon` tells the view class that if the user touches down, don't draw a path, instead draw that icon.

Comment: please see the main activity

Comment: Ok, I removed the line ` mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);` and the image retains if I go to application view of my phone then return back to the application. But it still doesn't draw on my first touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had to remove the line
`mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);` 
from my `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method and call `invalidate()`